# Problème with Imagemagick -geometry syntax

Tags: imagemagick

The following command works perfectly.

```
montage src-1.png src-2.png -geometry 400x+5+5 dst.png
```

But the following command returns an error.

```
montage src-1.png src-2.png -geometry 400+5+5 dst.png
montage: invalid argument for option '-geometry': 400+5+5 @error/montage.c/MontageImageCommand/1011.
```

Reading, [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry) documentation, the second command should be the correct one. If only the width is set, the geometry syntax should be `400+5+5`. It's working without offset.

Comment: What is the question exactly please? You seem to be saying the first command works correctly like the documentation says, and the second command doesn't work exactly like we expect it not to.

Comment: Sorry, the documentation says the **second** command should be the correct one. I just edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

You have `-geometry 400x+5+5` with an "x" in the first command. In the second, the one that generates the error, you have `-geometry 400+5+5` without the "x".

Try this...

```
... -geometry 400x+5+5 ...
```

I tested these commands with "montage" in ImageMagick v6, and got the same error when omitting the "x". Apparently when using a single value for the width and height, you must still include the "x" for IM to recognize it as a valid geometry argument.

Comment: I'm using ImageMagick 7.0.10-34 but if I'm not mistaken, the documentation says that you shouldn't put the "x".

Comment: It may be that the documentation is incorrect, but the command works properly for me with the "x" with IMv6.9.11-29 and IMv7.0.10-31, and generates an error in both without it. So that appears to be the solution.

Comment: Indeed, I'm just a little surprised that the documentation is incorrect.

Comment: That document is correct, but it is a general document for many features such as resize, crop, extent, etc. Some features do not make sense in all situations. When using -geometry with offsets, you should specify the x, so as to tell it whether the size is W or H. So 400x or x400 or 400x400.

Comment: That was not clear, because of "Below, {size} refers to any of the forms above." and 400x is not one of the above forms.